# Curl with restful API

Tags: rest, curl, elasticsearch

My pc is windows 10. I want to use curl command to get the data from elasticsearch, but I have some problems.
this is my curl command (a small test):
curl "http://localhost:9200/_search" -d '{"query": {"match_all": {}}}'

and the cmd show the error:

`{"error":"Content-Type header [application/x-www-form-urlencoded] is not supported","status":406}curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched brace in column 1
curl: (3) [globbing] empty string within braces in column 2`

could anyone help me?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you need to provide the proper Content-Type header as well:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"query": {"match_all": {}}}' "http://localhost:9200/_search"
```

Comment: curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched brace in column 1
curl: (3) [globbing] empty string within braces in column 2

Comment: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"json_parse_exception","reason":"Unexpected char
acter (''' (code 39)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 't
rue', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.ByteBu
fStreamInput@ed80fa5; line: 1, column: 2]"}],"type":"json_parse_exception","reas
on":"Unexpected character (''' (code 39)): expected a valid value (number, Strin
g, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.tra
nsport.netty4.ByteBufStreamInput@ed80fa5; line: 1, column: 2]"},"status":500}

Comment: oh I found the problem is that before the Double quotes need to add \  (backslash)

Comment: curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET http://120.127.160.91:9200/logstash-2018.01.05 -d "{\"query\": {\"match_all\": {}}}"